# When multiple individuals place identically priced offers, how does Stellar decide who will make the sale?

Tags: offer

I inadvertently placed an offer to sell an asset in exchange for XLM only to find that I had put the same asking price as another individual.  My XLM was added to the other sellers XLM in the order-book. So I was wondering, if someone accepted the offer, which of the two sellers would make the sale, me or the other individual.

Put another way, if sellers A, B and C place a bid to sell an asset to buy XLM and a buyer places an offer to a purchase that asset, how does Stellar decide which of the sellers will make the sale?

Let’s say that seller A has 10 XLM to swap, seller B has 50 and seller C has 800 XLM to swap. Is it based on the amount of XLM, where the individual with the most XLM makes the sale? Or is it based on the date which the offer was made, such as First In First Out?

Answer (score 1):

In the Stellar network, when multiple individuals place identically priced offers, the network prioritizes the offer that was placed first. This is because the offers are ordered in a "book" based on their price and time of submission. When a new offer is submitted with an identical price as an existing offer, it is added to the book after the existing offer. When a trade is initiated, the network searches through the book to find the best available match. If multiple offers match, the offer that was placed first is executed first.

It is worth noting that the Stellar network uses a decentralized order book, which means that the book is maintained by a network of independent nodes rather than a central authority. This ensures that the book is transparent, accessible to everyone, and resistant to manipulation.